# Cubic "bezier" curve of grade n

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, computational-geometry, graphics

This is code I wrote for calculating bezier curves as quickly and RAM efficiently as possible.

I would like to know if there are faster ways to optimize anything, because I am very new to C++ and efficiency methods.

Lastly, if there is a variable that could be more explicitly named, also let me know.

```
#include <vector>

double* bezier_interp (double* points, double* temp_space, int temp_space_size, int points_total, double t_step_t) {
    memcpy(temp_space, points, temp_space_size);
    for (int pointsi = points_total; pointsi > 1; --pointsi){
        for (int pointsj = 1; pointsj < pointsi; pointsj++) {
            points[pointsj-1] -= (points[pointsj-1] - points[pointsj]) * t_step_t;
        }
    }
    return points;
}

double* bezier_t (double* numbers, int points_total, int definition) {
    double *result = new double[definition];

    double t_step = 1 / ((double) definition - 1);
    double t_step_t;
    double* temp_space = new double[points_total];
    int temp_space_size = sizeof(*temp_space) * points_total;
    for (int t = 0; t < definition; t++) {
        t_step_t = t * t_step;
        result[t] = *bezier_interp(numbers, temp_space, temp_space_size, points_total, t_step_t);
    }
    delete[] temp_space;
    return result;
}

#include<iostream>

int main() {
    double numbers_x[] = {
        0, 0, 4, 4
    };
    double numbers_y[] = {
        0, 4, 4, 0
    };
    int definition = 8;
    double* xs = bezier_t(numbers_x, 4, definition);
    double* ys = bezier_t(numbers_y, 4, definition);
    for (int dix = 0; dix < definition; dix++){ std::cout << xs[dix] << "\t"; }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int diy = 0; diy < definition; diy++){ std::cout << ys[diy] << "\t"; }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Memory management

The `bezier_t` function allocates memory for `result` variable:

> ```
>     double *result = new double[definition];
> ```

The function returns `result` and the memory is never freed.
Be careful with memory management.
The cleanest solution is to allocate and free memory in the same method.
But this function obviously cannot do that,
because it needs to return the result right?

To overcome this,
you can allocate `result` before calling `bezier_t`,
pass it to `bezier_t` as a parameter,
and free sometime after `bezier_t` returns.

Related and similar to this is the `bezier_interp` function.
It takes the `points` array as parameter,
modifies its contents,
and returns it.
It's not wrong to return it,
but it's a bit confusing,
because whenever I see something that looks like a pointer,
I have to check where it comes from,
where is it allocated and freed.

You could change `bezier_interp` to return `void`,
and write the loop body in `bezier_t` like this:

```
bezier_interp(numbers, temp_space, temp_space_size, points_total, t_step_t);
result[t] = numbers[0];
```

#### Limit variables to the smallest scope necessary

There's no need to declare the `t_step_t` variable before the loop:

> ```
> double t_step_t;
> for (int t = 0; t < definition; t++) {
>     t_step_t = t * t_step;
>     // ...
> ```

It's better to declare the variable inside the loop:

```
for (int t = 0; t < definition; t++) {
    double t_step_t = t * t_step;
    // ...
```

This way it cannot be accidentally misused outside the loop.
Sure, in this program such accidents seem unlikely for now,
but it's a good habit to get used to.

And perhaps `t_t_step` would be somewhat better name than `t_step_t`.

#### Simplify

This expression can be written simpler:

> ```
> double t_step = 1 / ((double) definition - 1);
> ```

Like this:

```
double t_step = 1. / (definition - 1);
```

#### Misc

I'm totally with @vnp: `pointi` and `pointj` are really hard to read,
simple `i` and `j` would be better.

Comment: Thank you janos and @vnp, this is my first code review post, should I resubmit my code, or update this question by appending the newest version here? How does further revision take place?

Comment: Don't edit the code in the question, as that would invalidate the answers. Create a new question with your updated code, and include a link to this question, for reference.

Answer (score 2):

- `#include <vector>` is pointless. There is no vectors in the code.
- Unless I am missing something obvious, `temp_space` plays no role in the calculations.
- `pointsi` and `pointsj` do not sound right (too much of visual noise makes it hard to tell them apart). It is one of the rear cases where I'd go for plain `i` and `j`.
- `t_step_t` is confusing, and strictly speaking unnecessary. You may calculate it at the point of invocation as

  ```
  result[t] = *besier_interp(..., t * t_step);
  ```

Comment: No you are right, I wasn't using my temp_space for my calculations as I intended, because I wanted to be using the temp_space to store my evaluations in between `pointsj` and `pointsi` for loops.

Comment: I had vector included for the `memcpy` function that I was using. I'll change it to `<cstring>` or something.